# Apache Transaction:write file transactionally - how to use resourceId

Tags: java, file, apache-commons, transactional

If anybody implemented transactional writing to file,please, assist me.
Related topic was discussed in earlier thread([transactional write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311050/transaction-mode-for-file-operations-in-java)).

Use case is following:
***if writing to log file is failed,that appropriate DB transaction shoud be rolled back.***

So the writinig to file should be performed in transactional way.

I've chosen [Apache Commons Transaction](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/) lib.
And have issue,that doesn't let me go further,because haven't found appropriate documentation or examples.

I have created instance of FileResourceManager:

> FileResourceManager frm = new
>   FileResourceManager("c:\cur",
>   "c:\cur", true, logger);

As I understand from this [Apache Commons Transaction tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/file/index.html),i should implement following steps:

1. start transaction:
    `frm.start();`
2. get transaction Id for it:
    `transactionId = frm.generatedUniqueTxId();`
3. call method, that is needed, e.g. writeResource with transactionId and resourceId:
   `frm.writeResource(transactionId, resourceId);`

And here is ambiguity:
a) how can I connect `resourceId` with real resource,that I should write transactioanally?
b) how do my file,that I will write transactionally will now about `resourceId`?

Thank you for advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far nobody answers, I try do that from my latest experience.

Useful documentataion:
[example2(.ppt)](http://www.slideshare.net/junyuo/transactional-file-system-in-java-commons-transaction-499821)

Simplified algorithm looks like(actually,depicted in example2):
**1.** initialize [FileResourceManager](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-transaction/apidocs/org/apache/commons/transaction/file/FileResourceManager.html) 
**2.** start FileResourceManager 
**3.** get transaction Id from FileResourceManager instance
**4.** start transaction with transaction Id from step 3
**5.** write resource you need  - here is mentioned write it **transactionally**
,so looks like it's the major step!
**6.** commit or rollback transaction

Note: ***resourceId***,about i asked in ,my question, is simply ***name*** of ***transactional file***.
This naming doesn't depict very good this attribute.

Code, I used:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(FileAppender.class);
private static LoggerFacade loggerFacade = new Log4jLogger(logger);

private static String tempDir = (String) System.getProperties().get("java.io.tmpdir");

private FileResourceManager frm = new FileResourceManager(tempDir, tempDir, false, loggerFacade);
private static OutputStream outputStream;

public void writeOut(E event) throws IOException {
    Object txId = null;
    try {
        frm.start();
        txId = frm.generatedUniqueTxId();
        frm.startTransaction(txId);
        outputStream = frm.writeResource(txId, fileName, true);
        frm.commitTransaction(txId);

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("DB rollback");
    }
}
```

Comment: Every single link is dead! Please update if you can. Thanks.