# Spring MVC synchronize access to a shared resource

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

The scenario is the following:
I use a spring controller to read and edit single file on the file system.
There are many user who can edit the file and many who can read that file.
I don`t want to end up writing changes to the file while other users are 
reading from that file. I want multiple readers at a time or a single writer at a time.
To achieve that I used ReentrantReadWriteLock (It allows multiple readers 
or a single writer at a time.).

BUT to use my ReentrantReadWriteLock I need to spawn my own threads that are synchronized on that lock. I found out that it is not a good idea to spawn custom threads in a Webcontainers.

Is there any good approach to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Take look also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311050/transaction-mode-for-file-operations-in-java

Comment: The api seems depracted: "We have decided to move the project to dormant as we are convinced that the main advertised feature transactional file access can not be implemented reliably."

Comment: you can use the devOps process, create a lock file in the file system

Comment: Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: After reading about the thread model of servlets:[1]
And how spring controllers are allocated and managed:[2]
I realized that:
Web containers have a pool of threads and these threads are allocated per request. Spring beans/controllers are singletons by default. So threads are accessing the controller concurrently.I do not need to spawn my own threads. I just need to use the ReentrantReadWriteLock to sync. the "request" threads.


  [1]: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-concurrency.html
  [2]: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/understanding-spring-mvc